# Problem with google Natural language sentiment analysis

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform

I have the code for performing sentiment analysis of a statement or a group of statements using google cloud natural language API. But, when the project is run, i do not get any output, even though there is no error in my code.

I have tried implementing the sample android application provided by android too, for implementing the sentiment analysis, though the code runs perfectly fine, i cannot understand the code. Here is the link for that, any help in understanding the code will be appreciated -  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/nl/Language

These are my dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-language:1.70.0'
```

the android portion in my app level gradle file looks like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.googlesentiment"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
             optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    }
}
```

I have a class named MyAnalyser where the main code for sentiment analysis lies . It is as follows:

```
package com.example.googlesentiment;

import com.google.cloud.language.v1.AnalyzeSentimentResponse;

import com.google.cloud.language.v1.Document;
import com.google.cloud.language.v1.Document.Type;

import com.google.cloud.language.v1.LanguageServiceClient;
import com.google.cloud.language.v1.Sentiment;

public class MyAnalyser {

    String magnitude,score;
    private final static String TAG = "My Tag";

    public  Sentiment analyzeSentimentText(String text) throws Exception {
        // [START language_sentiment_text]
        // Instantiate The Languageclient 
           com.google.cloud.language.v1.LanguageServiceClient
        try (LanguageServiceClient language = LanguageServiceClient.create()) 
         {
            Document doc = Document.newBuilder()
                    .setContent(text)
                    .setType(Type.PLAIN_TEXT)
                    .build();
            AnalyzeSentimentResponse response = 
                           language.analyzeSentiment(doc);
            Sentiment sentiment = response.getDocumentSentiment();
            if (sentiment == null) {
                System.out.println("No sentiment found");
            } else {
                magnitude = Float.toString(sentiment.getMagnitude());
                score = Float.toString(sentiment.getMagnitude());
                Log.d(TAG,Float.toString(sentiment.getMagnitude()));
                Log.d(TAG,Float.toString(sentiment.getScore()));
            }

            Log.d(TAG,sentiment.toString());
            return sentiment;
        }
        // [END language_sentiment_text]
    }


    public String getMagnitude(){
        return magnitude;
    }
    public String getScore(){
        return score;
    }


}
```

This is my mainActivity.java file's on create method: On click of the button, the sentiment analysis is to be performed, but when i click the button, nothing happens:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    enterSample = this.findViewById(R.id.enter_sample_text);
    button = this.findViewById(R.id.button_analyse);
    textView = this.findViewById(R.id.get_sentiment_and_entity);

    sampleText = enterSample.getText().toString();
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG,"this is starting");
            MyAnalyser analyser = new MyAnalyser();
            try {
                Log.d(TAG,"this is starting");
                analyser.analyzeSentimentText(sampleText);
                Log.d(TAG,"this is starting");
                textView.setText(analyser.getMagnitude() + "\n" + 
                analyser.getScore());
                Log.d(TAG,"this is starting");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


}
```

I expect a floating type(converted to string) value for sentiment and magnitude. but get no output